# unexpected behavior using bufferWhen operator and EMPTY

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

The main goal is to be able to disable buffering, but when it is enabled, to behave like bufferTime. I achieved that using bufferWhen. From the factory function a timer observable is returned, with 0ms (if buffering is disabled) otherwise 2000ms.

I replaced timer(0) with EMPTY but this resulted to emitting an unexpected number of times

you can reproduce here: https://playcode.io/1007338

Answer (score 0):

I'm 100% sure but here is my educated guess:

You have to know that RxJS observable are not always asynchronous.

You have a good example here with `timer(0)` and `EMPTY.pipe(startWith(1)))`

```
timer(0).subscribe(console.log);
EMPTY.pipe(startWith(1))).subscribe(console.log)
```

Will log `1` then `0`.

That's because `timer` is based on the `setInterval` (which is asynchronous) and `EMPTY.pipe(startWith(1)))` will be evaluated synchronously.

Since `bufferWhen` expects an async observable, that's why your are observing a difference here.

Comment: Thanks for answering, you are probably right. Where is it stated that bufferWhen expects an async observable? I was not able to find it in rxjs docs. Could you provide a link?

Comment: @zdevm That's what I guessed reading [the source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/bufferWhen.ts)